# Encoding / encryption in Classic ASP

Tags: asp-classic, character-encoding

I have two web pages, /default.asp and /mobile/default.asp.

Both pages have the following declaration:

meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8"

In addition, both pages use the same include file which provides access to some string encryption and decryption functions.

THe problem i am experiencing is that two pages using the same charset encoding and the same encryption function are giving two different strings when the same string is encrypted with the same key.

Any ideas? The incorrect output contains lots of black diamonds with question marks in them. In HEX, these appear as FD FF.

ADDITIONAL - The encrypted data is getting stored in a SQL database and this is how i am seeing the two different encryption results.

So, its the same encryption function with the output being in the same SQL database but from two different asp pages (but they are using the same charset).

Answer (score 1):

you can set your server-side codepage as follows to UTF-8 :

```
<%@ Language="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
```

or

```
<% 
Response.CodePage = "utf-8"
%>
```

It is common to keep your output the same as your codepage. The output is what you are setting with the meta tag and could also be set as follows:

```
<% 
Response.Charset = "utf-8"
%>
```

Comment: Did the nonsense output stream change in anyway? If not, try to see if you're not having a caching issue... that can be pesky sometimes...  If it's not caching, could a different output from the two-way encryption otherwise come from the fact that your two pages are on a different level... I mean, could that influence your call to the encryption in any way perhaps? Hard to tell without seeing.

Comment: i'll investigate these options. Cheers :o)

Answer (score 0):

After about 8 hours of trial and error, i managed to find the problem.

THe ASP page itself was created and saved as UTF-8 encoded and it needed to be UTF-8 without BOM

Comment: You got me interested... I never heard of it. Was it caused by the editor you used? What was the actual solution then?

Comment: It was an option in the editor. I opened both files in Notepad++ and confirmed that the page that worked was UTF-8 without BOM (in the 'Encoding' menu) and the page that didn't work was just UTF-8. As soon as i changed this to UTF-8 without BOM, the encryption started working correctly. I wish i understood fully myself!!!